# how to load links on Webview?

Tags: javascript, android, web, webview

I have the following code which can load google map on Webview:

```
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().getBuiltInZoomControls();
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/javascript.html");
```

**javascript.html:**

```
function initialize() {

  //https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls
  latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.7628, -95.3831);
  window.android.JavaScript_Request_LatLng();
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: latLng
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: 'This is a marker'
    }); 

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Now, I like to load an image from this link:

[picture from a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia#/media/File:Brockhaus_Lexikon.jpg)

I heard about asynchronous, but I have no clue where to start.

Do I load an image on top of the Google Map or close google map webview first, and then load this image?

Can someone please give me some tips or a sample code?

Thank you very much for your help.